# Can you define a hasMany relationship with a HashMap in an extJs model?

Tags: extjs, model, hashmap

I have some json data with the following format:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "personMap":{
        "president":{"firstname":"Sookie","lastname":"Stackhouse"},
        "vicepresident":{"firstname":"Eric","lastname":"Northman"},
        "treasurer":{"firstname":"Alcide","lastname":"Herveaux"}
    }
}
```

How do I define my model so that the values in the map are loaded with the correct object type?  Is that possible?

The following will load the data but the values are not typed as 'Person' objects:

```
Ext.define('Committee', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [ 'id', 'personMap' ]
});
```

The following would expect personMap to be an array not a map:

```
Ext.define('Committee', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [ 'id' ],
    hasMany: [{
        model: 'Person',
        name: 'personMap'
    }]
});

Ext.define('Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [ 'firstname', 'lastname' ]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The hasMany config only applies to arrays. Changing the data structure to,

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "personMap": [
    {
      "firstname": "Sookie",
      "lastname": "Stackhouse",
      "title": "president"
    },
    {
      "firstname": "Eric",
      "lastname": "Northman",
      "title": "vicepresident"
    },
    {
      "firstname": "Alcide",
      "lastname": "Herveaux",
      "title": "treasurer"
    }
  ]
}
```

will do the trick, but if that's not an option then the hasMany config cannot be used.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't involve me changing the data structure.  Or, at least I want to identify the hole in extjs that prevents you from using the data in this way.

Comment: You should still be able to access the records data like, `record.get('personMap').president`, then to apply that data to a model you can do, `var model = Ext.create('Person', record.get('personMap').president);`, but you'll lose the persons title since that is not a part of the model.